# Issue regarding bootstrap collapse and it's effect on DOM

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my webpage. Now I want to achieve a particular effect.I have a div with class name "container-fluid" and h2 tag with a text under it. Just like the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;text-align: center;height: 76px;">
    <br>
    <h2 id="mesheading" style="color: #a76281; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: -4px; font-family: 'brandon_grotesquebold'; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px;">
        Helping manufacturers save 20%-30% of the store cost &nbsp;
        <span>
            <button class="button_one" type="button" onclick="open_win_two()">
                LEARN MORE
            </button>
        </span>
    </h2><br>
</div>
```

My requirement is that when the browser window will be collapsed the font size of h2 tag will become smaller. For example it will become 10px.

And on expanding the browser window on its actual size it will move back to its original font size i.e 14px

I have done quite a few research about collapse related events of jQuery. But it did not help me.

So please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Look up css media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Changing css on elements depending on the screen size.

**Solution**

You can use media queries to change font size of your `h2` or any element.

**Examples**

Use this media query to set a condition for anything between the two widths you provide in the query. you can reuse this to create multiple scenarios just by changing the width of `min` and `max` `width`.

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
      .container-fluid h2 {
         font-size: 10px;
}
    }
```

Then outside of a media query you could do this as a default for anything that does not fall into the condition of any of your `media queries`.

```
.container-fluid h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

**Targeting Specific Devices**

Here is some of the more common necessary media queries to target popular devices.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste someone else's answer in another question at least give them credit for their work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan +1

Comment: I did not copy and post someone else's code. This came out of my css file I keep on hand. I have tons more if you would like me to flood the wall with them. I have posted this all over the internet when this question gets asked all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use default breakpoints of media query  like this:

**CSS**

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
  @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .container-fluid h2 {
      your font size
      }
    }

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .container-fluid h2 {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  }

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .container-fluid h2 {
      your font size
    }
   }

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
     .container-fluid h2 {
        your font size
    }
  }
```